# Too many redirects when I try to set up HTTPS in Laravel - Nothing works

Tags: php, laravel, https

I've got a project in Laravel and I bought SSL. It works when I try to run my website by keyboard - https ://domain.com however it is required to force a HTTPS scheme all the time. And I tried to do everything: 
1. htaccess 
2. change env 
3. Api Service Provider 
4. api.php and so on...

htacces works fine and set up https liks but there is an error - To many redirects - In console in Chrome I see that my domain is opening in loop. 
I can't find the solution - tried everything form Stack's forum and it doesn't work.

Comment: Please add your htaccess config.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding in

app/providers/AppServiceProvider

```
if(env(' APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
    $url->forceSchema('https'); 
}
```

This will set all resources to HTTPS

Worked for me once.